# how to add a meta box to wordpress pages

Tags: wordpress, meta-boxes

i want to make this code for pages

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'meta_box_video' );
function meta_box_video()
{
    add_meta_box( 'video-meta-box-id', 'Video Embed', 'meta_box_callback', 'post', 'normal', 'high' );
}

function meta_box_callback( $post )
{
    $values = get_post_custom( $post->ID );
    $selected = isset( $values['meta_box_video_embed'] ) ? $values['meta_box_video_embed'][0] : '';

    wp_nonce_field( 'my_meta_box_nonce', 'meta_box_nonce' );
    ?>
    <p>
        <label for="meta_box_video_embed"><p>Video Embed</p></label>
        <textarea name="meta_box_video_embed" id="meta_box_video_embed" cols="62" rows="5" ><?php echo $selected; ?></textarea>
    </p>
    <p>Leave it Empty ( if you want to use an image thumbnail ) .</p>
    <?php   
}

add_action( 'save_post', 'meta_box_video_save' );
function meta_box_video_save( $post_id )
{
    // Bail if we're doing an auto save
    if( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return;

    // if our nonce isn't there, or we can't verify it, bail
    if( !isset( $_POST['meta_box_nonce'] ) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['meta_box_nonce'], 'my_meta_box_nonce' ) ) return;

    // if our current user can't edit this post, bail
    if( !current_user_can( 'edit_post' ) ) return;

    // now we can actually save the data
    $allowed = array( 
        'a' => array( // on allow a tags
            'href' => array() // and those anchords can only have href attribute
        )
    );

    // Probably a good idea to make sure your data is set

    if( isset( $_POST['meta_box_video_embed'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'meta_box_video_embed', $_POST['meta_box_video_embed'] );

}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This:

```
function meta_box_video()
{
    add_meta_box( 'video-meta-box-id', 'Video Embed', 'meta_box_callback', 'post', 'normal', 'high' );
}
```

Should specify `page` not `post`.

```
function meta_box_video()
{                                      // --- Parameters: ---
    add_meta_box( 'video-meta-box-id', // ID attribute of metabox
                  'Video Embed',       // Title of metabox visible to user
                  'meta_box_callback', // Function that prints box in wp-admin
                  'page',              // Show box for posts, pages, custom, etc.
                  'normal',            // Where on the page to show the box
                  'high' );            // Priority of box in display order
}
```

Take a look at the [**Codex for add_meta_box()**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box). The examples are very helpful. The portion you are interested in is under "Parameter". The fourth parameter allows you to specify whether you want the metabox on pages, posts, etc.

Comment: Can you explain how to show these values in fronted