# Wordpress meta-box - How to add meta-box to pages?

Tags: php, wordpress, meta-boxes

How can I add [meta-box](http://metabox.io/) to pages and posts?

I have this [code](https://github.com/rilwis/meta-box/blob/master/demo/demo.php) added to `themes/package/demo.php`, and that I can see **Standard Fields** and **Advanced Fields** in my posts, but I **only** see **Standard Fields** in pages.

Can I have **Advanced Fields** in pages as well?

There is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6890617/how-to-add-a-meta-box-to-wordpress-pages) here, but where should I put this script below?

```
function meta_box_video()
{                                      // --- Parameters: ---
    add_meta_box( 'video-meta-box-id', // ID attribute of metabox
                  'Video Embed',       // Title of metabox visible to user
                  'meta_box_callback', // Function that prints box in wp-admin
                  'page',              // Show box for posts, pages, custom, etc.
                  'normal',            // Where on the page to show the box
                  'high' );            // Priority of box in display order
}
```

Comment: see here http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box#Examples

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
function myplugin_add_meta_box() {

$screens = array( 'post', 'page' );

foreach ( $screens as $screen ) {

    add_meta_box(
        'myplugin_sectionid',
        __( 'My Post Section Title', 'myplugin_textdomain' ),
        'myplugin_meta_box_callback',
        $screen
    );
}
} add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'myplugin_add_meta_box' );
```

Comment: Hello, put it in your functions.php

Comment: He is within your theme folder. If plugin, you can enter a default file it.